# Why doesn't Safari copy URL parameters of a link when using the 'copy' from menu?

Tags: safari, copy-paste, url

I found a strange behaviour on Safari that seems to be affecting URL sharing.
If I copy the url by selecting all coping it I can share the full link. Such as [www.somesite.com/somepage?params=somename&urlparams=someothername](http://www.somesite.com/somepage?params=somename&urlparams=someothername)

When I copy paste a link by using "copy" from the menu, all the url params that are in the url are gone and I can only copy paste this: [www.somesite.com/somepage](http://www.somesite.com/somepage)

Is there a bug on safari or some option that stops params from being shared?

Currently this happens on: software version 15.4

Comment: My guess is they're stripping parameters in an attempt to provide some kind of privacy and/or prevent leakage of tokens embedded in URLs. Either way, it's likely intentional.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that ios shares canonicals of the website, not the actual link. The only solution was to remove the canonical from the pages that needs to be shared with params.

Comment: If the page needs to be shared with params then the canonical URL should include those params

Comment: The thing is google does not recommend that... which was my reasoning since SEO is very important for us.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls

Comment: If your URL requires the parameters to load then that’s the canonical URL. If the parameters are for tracking then it’s not canonical and shouldn’t be shared. That’s what Google says and that’s how Safari works.